# Can't reshape an array of size 153600 into (392, 392)

Tags: python, numpy, plot

I am looking a way to reshape an array of size 153600, but no luck! 
Code:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (12, 6))

for i in range(1, 1+8):
    fig.add_subplot(2,4, i)
    plt.imshow(q.loc[:, f'PC-{i}'].values.reshape(392, 392), cmap='nipy_spectral')
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.title(f'Band - {i}') 

plt.savefig('IP_PCA_Bands.png')
```

Error:

```
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 153600 into shape (392,392)
```

Any solution for this problem in Python 3?

Comment: 392*392=153664, so the reshaping is not possible. I think the closest shape you can get is (400, 384) or (400, 384).

Comment: In other words, you need another 64 elements in the array if you want to do the reshape you are suggesting.

Comment: I think this should do it, thanks!